# Copying raw data into specific cells of a target sheet

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I am trying to write the Output of my Script to the second worksheet of an Excel workbook. Now when I use the following code I always get the error

> Microsoft VBScript Compilation error : Expected end of statement.

Can you let me know where I may be going wrong? If you want to look at the entire code feel free to let me know.

The code snippet to write the output is as follows:

```
Set targetsheet.Cells(1,1).Value = objOutput.Write objUser.samaccountname & ";" _
    & objUser.GivenName & ";" & objUser.sn & ";" & objUser.DisplayName & ";" _
    & ObjMail & ";" & InfosysSite & ";=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(E" & count _
    & ",'Infosys employees'!C:C,1,FALSE)=E" & count & ",""Yes""),""No"")" _
    & ";=IF(G" & count & "=""Yes"",VLOOKUP(E" & count _
    & ",'Infosys employees'!C:D,2,FALSE),""Missing"")" & ";" & ObjUser.Title _
    & ";" & ObjUser.Co & ";" & Manager & ";" & objUser.employeeID & ";" _
    & Account_locked & ";" & last_Login & ";" & last_Logon_timestamp & ";" _
    & pwd_never_expire & ";" & Last_pwd_Changed & ";" & User_must_change_pwd _
    & ";" & objUser.whenCreated & ";" & objUser.whenChanged & ";" _
    & objUser.description & ";" & objUser.distinguishedName & ";" & vbCrLf
```

Comment: you are missing the () for objOutput.Write.

Comment: I added the same to objOutput.Write() but I am still getting the same error of Microsoft VBScript Compilation error : Expected end of statement

Comment: Are you sure its expected end of statement error and not object not found error?

Comment: Yes it's the same Expected end of statement error for the same line. :(

Comment: @PankajJaju - .Write is not a function, it does not return anything. So param () are **verboten**.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner - Not sure what objOutput object is as OP didn't pasted complete code. So if I test it in black box mode, without the brackets VBA will show syntax error. Also, if he is just trying to update the value, using Set is also incorrect. But I guess you assumed correctly and OP is trying to update targetsheet.Cells(1,1).Value in some text file.

Answer (score 0):

You get a 1025 error, when you try to call a sub/submethod in an assigment:

```
>> v = SubOrSubMethod "very long string"
>>
Error Number:       1025
Error Description:  Anweisungsende erwartet
```

So assign your (horrible) string expression to a variable:

```
s = objUser.samaccountname &";" & ... &";" & vbcrlf
```

and use that to fill the cell's value:

```
targetsheet.Cells(1,1).Value = s
```

Mark the deleted `Set`! You want to assign a string, not an object. Whether a dignostic output:

```
objOutput.Write s
```

makes sense in your context, is for you to decide.